# reclaim space after moving indexes to file group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an extremely large database and most of the space is the index size. I moved several indexes to a different file group (just to experiment) but no matter what I do I cannot reduce the size of the MDF.

I tried shrink database, shrink files, rebuilding clustered index. What can I do to reclaim that space in the MDF? I've moved 25GB worth of indexes to a different file group. Is it even possible to reduce my mdf by that same 25gb (or close to it)?

SQL Server 2008 Enterprise

```
Group   Total Space     Avail Space
PRIMARY 388485.000000   27126.3125000
Index   24778.375000    26.6250000
```

Options I tried for shrink:

```
TSQL: 
1. DBCC SHRINKFILE (1, 10);
2. DBCC SHRINKFILE (1, TRUNCATE_ONLY);

UI: Shrink database: 
1. Without 'reorganize files...'
2. With 'reorganize files...'
2a. set max free space = 10%
2b. set max free space = 90%
2c. set max free space = 75%

UI: Shrink files: (type =data, group = primary, filename = db name)
1. Release unused space
2. reorganize pages... setting shrink file = 2GB (max it allows)
3. reorganize pages... setting shrink file = 361,360 (min allowed)
```

did not try 'Empty file' option because that doesnt seem like what i want.

Comment: Does your DB show 15GB of free space in your (I'm assuming) Primary file group?

Comment: @JNK Primary shows 27,126.31 (mb)

Comment: @JNK TotalSpace: 388,485 Available Space: 27,126.

Comment: @Titan - what EXACTLY are you doing to reclaim the space?  If it's through the gui, what options are checked?

Comment: @JNK i've tried all sorts of things. since this is on my local i'm doing whatever i can find on google. tried shrink db & shrink files with all diff options set. tried rebuilding indexes tried reorganizing indexes, ran DBCC UPDATEUSAGE and a few others. nothing has made a dent. I ran shrink right after i restored the db (before moving indexes to filegroups) and it reduced in size by 3GB but thats it.

Comment: @JNK shrink was all through the UI

Comment: @titan - I get that, but what exactly are you clicking/  Can you show a screenshot?  Saying "i tried all the options" is probably not accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, try through the UI a "Shrink Database" with "0%" max free space.

The 10% setting you used before "worked" but your 27 gigs free space is under 10% (its like 7%) of your total DB.

Bear in mind this may cause you performance issues down  the road since your DB will need to grow again, and this will also cause performance issues now since shrinking leads to fragmentation which is bad.

However if space is  your primary concern the above method **should** work.

Comment: I've been running DBCC SHRINKFILE (1,10) for the last 22 minutes and it's still going so i think you're correct. I'll let you know what happens when it's done. Right now we need to get the size down to something manageable for backups. I'll break it up into filegroups as we see fit then partition off big tables and I think we'll be good to go.

Comment: Moved more indexes into the other file group (around 35gb now) and did a shrink with 5% and now the mdf is down to 377gb. So it worked.

Comment: @Titan - happy to help.  Watch out for performance hits, though.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed in the past that shrinking the data file in smaller chunks can be more effective than trying to shrink it all in one go.  If you were to attempt to use a similar strategy then you'd want to do something like below:

```
DECLARE @targetSize AS INT = 388000;
DECLARE @desiredFinalSize AS INT = 362000;
DECLARE @increment AS INT = 300;
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(200);

WHILE @targetSize > @desiredFinalSize
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'DBCC SHRINKFILE(''MyDataFileName'', ' + CAST(@targetSize AS VARCHAR(10)) + ');'
    SELECT @sql;
    EXEC(@sql);

    SET @targetSize = @targetSize - @increment; 
END
```

Answer (score 1):

This step looks wrong

> UI: Shrink files: (type =data, group = primary, filename = db name)
>       1. Release unused space
>       2. reorganize pages... setting shrink file = 2GB (max it allows)
>       3. reorganize pages... setting shrink file = **361,360** (min allowed)

Among your question steps, this is the right one.

1. Shrink File
2. File type (Data), group (PRIMARY) Name ()
3. Shrink Action = reorganize pages (=move to front), Shrink File *

Shrink File is entered in MB, so a value of 361,360 would be a third of a Terabyte. The easiest way to set it to minimum is to enter 0, tab out -> it will replace with the min allowed.

> Right now we need to get the size down to something manageable for backups

This is completely the wrong way to go about it.  BACKUPs **do not** include free space, so whether your primary mdf file has 100GB of free space or 1TB, as long as the data resides on 200GB, that is the size of the backup files.  For SQL Server 2008, you can use "with compression", which gives an average size of about 1/6th.

Comment: Thanks. You're correct. But we're moving indexes to a different file group(s) and we're going to back up the primary data group only.

Comment: @Titan - I understand that but this question is about "removing free space from primary". This step is not necessary for that purpose, and sometimes not really required for a growing db that will eventually reclaim the space.

Comment: the problem right now is that the db is 450gb. If we move indexes to file groups we will eat up another 200GB which totals 600GB. We don't have that much space.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes i've noticed that if i shrink down a file, it won't shrink below the initial size set on the file.  could you go see what the initial file size of the file is?